# Is the Westerosi heraldry similar to western europe medieval heraldry?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Similar to our world, heraldry play an important role to distinguish noble Houses or singular character. But did the westerosi heraldry follow the same rules as ours ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR**: 
Inspired, but not similar in all points

**Long answer**:

There are some diferences between westerosi and european heraldry, as there are lot of rules in real world that are not followed in westeros:

- No particular jargon: In our world, there is a particular jargon to describe coats of arms, for colors and figures. For example, we don't say "a golden lion on red background" but "gules, a lion or". Westerosi seems to lack this specific kinds of terms
- Rule of tincture: One basic rule of heraldry is the rule of tincture: metal should not be put on metal, nor colour on colour. Metal refers to gold and silver, while colors are azure(blue), gules(red), sable(black), vert(green) and purpure(purple). 
  [image: tincture]

Therefore, some sigils like Targaryen (gules and sable are both colors) don't follow the rules.

[image: targaryen]

- Limited number of tinctures: in real world, there are only two metals and five colors, and for example, two variant of greens are both considered "vert". Therefore, some sigils like Stark's (as grey and white are both considered "argent") or Duncan's(using a color gradient) don't follow the rules.

[image: Stark]
[image: Dunk]

Comment: I’m disinclined to upvote, 1. Because of the lack of a sourced confirmation on the level of inspiration from Western European medieval heraldry, and 2 because there certainly exist heralds that are colour on colour. **tl;dr** me likey sources

Comment: @Edlothiad - you mean there are coats of arms that are color on color.  In English heralds are persons whose functions sometimes include heraldry.

Comment: @Kepotx - in English a sigil means a seal.  Many medieval and later people and institutions used and still use their coats of arms on their seals.  In Westeros a sigil may mean something similar to a coat of arms.  But in English the word sigil is not used to mean a coat of arms and it would be an error to to use it outside of discussion of Westeros emblems.  And I feel a little uncomfortable that you didn't mention that fact in your discussion.  However good a story the world of Westeros may be, it will have a bad influence if it leads to people calling coats of arm sigils.